# Issue in Pyqt with next and previous Pages

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, window, qwidget

so I'm currently working on a little project but I have an issue and all what I've tried did not work. I have 2 files :
Page1test :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QWidget, QLabel
import sys

from page2test import Page2

class Page1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Page1, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Page 1")

        label1 = QLabel(self)
        label1.setText("\n PAGE 1")

        self.btn_inMyApp = QPushButton ('Next page', self)
        self.btn_inMyApp.setGeometry(1500,800,275,125)
        self.btn_inMyApp.clicked.connect(self.closePage1_OpenPage2)
        self.show()

    def closePage1_OpenPage2(self):
        self.Open = Page2()
        self.Open.showMaximized()
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Page1()
    window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And page2test :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QWidget, QLabel

from Page1test import Page1

class Page2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Page2, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test window principale")

        label1 = QLabel(self)
        label1.setText("\n Page2")

        self.btn_inMyApp = QPushButton ('previous Page', self)
        self.btn_inMyApp.setGeometry(1500,800,275,125)
        self.btn_inMyApp.clicked.connect(self.closePage2_OpenPage1)
        self.show()

    def closePage2_OpenPage1(self):
        self.Open = Page1()
        self.Open.showMaximized()
        self.close()
```

I run the code of Page1test : empty window with just a Qpushbutton "Next Page", goal : we click on it and it open Page 2 (and close Page 1). And, when we are in Page 2, we have A Qpushbutton with "Previous Page" and when we click on it, it opens page 1, and close Page 2. Like a loop.
But, when I run the code, it returns an error :
**cannot import name 'Page2' from partially initialized module 'page2test' (most likely due to a circular import)**

and I have no idea how to fix it...
If someone had an idea, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've finally found the solution, that was not so difficult in the end. Here it is (if it can help someone) :

Instead of making 2 files, I've done just 1 file. Here is the code :

````
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QWidget, QLabel, QMainWindow
import sys


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Page 1")

        label1 = QLabel(self)
        label1.setText("\n PAGE 1")

        self.btn_inMyApp = QPushButton ('Page suivante', self)
        self.btn_inMyApp.setGeometry(1500,800,275,125)
        self.btn_inMyApp.clicked.connect(self.closePage1_OpenPage2)
        self.show()

    def btn1_onClicked(self):
        pass

    def closePage1_OpenPage2(self):
        self.Open = NewApp()
        self.Open.showMaximized()
        self.close()


class NewApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewApp, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test window principale")

        label1 = QLabel(self)
        label1.setText("\n Page2")

        self.btn_inMyApp = QPushButton ('previous Page', self)
        self.btn_inMyApp.setGeometry(1500,800,275,125)
        self.btn_inMyApp.clicked.connect(self.closePage2_OpenPage1)
        self.show()

    def closePage2_OpenPage1(self):
        self.Open = MyApp()
        self.Open.showMaximized()
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```
````